# mongodb addToSet based on specific field

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo update that looks like:

```
Json.obj("$push" ->
  Json.obj("people" ->
    Json.obj("$each" -> person))
)
```

but person is an object that have personId, and I want the $push to only push unique people by personId, so don't push another person if the personId already exists

I know its possible to use addToSet instead of push but the person object also have another field sentTime which is timestamp that will be different so ig the addToSet will add it anyway.

could I explicitly tell him to do addToSet based on personId?